# Prob. 20, Sec. 2.2, in Leon's Linear Algebra Book: Numbers of additions and multiplications in calculation of the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction, recurrence-relations, determinant

Here is Prob. 20, Sec. 2.2, in the book *Linear Algebra With Applications* by Steven J. Leon and Lisette de Pillis, tenth edition:

> Show that evaluating the determinant of an $n \times n$ matrix by cofactors involves ( $n! - 1$ ) additions and $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} n! / k!$ multiplications.

My Attempt:

> Let $s_n$ and $m_n$ be the total numbers of additions (along with subtractions) and the total numbers of multiplications, respectively, involved in evaluating the determinant of an $n \times n$ matrix.

Method 1.

> For $n = 1$, we have
> $$
> \det \big( [ \begin{matrix} a \end{matrix} ] \big)  = a.
> $$
> So we have
> $$
> s_1 = 0 = 1! - 1 \tag{1} 
> $$
> and
> $$
> m_1 = 0 = \sum_{k=1}^{1-1} \frac{1!}{k!}. \tag{2}
> $$
> Thus our results hold for $n=1$.

> Now suppose that, for any given $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, we have
> $$
> s_n = n!-1 \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad m_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{n!}{k!}. 
> $$

> Let $A$ be an $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix. Then by using the cofactor expansion along the $i$th row of $A$, we have
> $$
> \det (A) = a_{i1} A_{i1} + \cdots + a_{in}A_{in} + a_{i, n+1} A_{i, n+1}. \tag{1}
> $$

> Now in the expression on the right-hand-side of (1), there are $n+1$ determinants of size $n \times n$, namely, $A_{ij}$ for each $j = 1, \ldots, n, n+1$. Each of these determinants involves ($n!-1$) additions and $\sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} n!/k!$ multiplications by virtue of our induction hypothesis. Moreover, in evaluating $\det (A)$ we need to perform an additional $n$ additions and an additional $n+1$ multiplications.

> Therefore we have
> $$
> \begin{align} 
> s_{n+1} &= n + (n+1) (n! - 1) \\ 
> &= n + (n+1) n! - (n+1) \\ 
> &= (n+1)! - 1,
> \end{align} 
> $$
> and also
> $$
> \begin{align} 
> m_n &= (n+1) + (n+1) \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{n!}{k!} \\ 
> &= \frac{(n+1)!}{n!} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{ (n+1) n! }{ k!} \\ 
> &= \frac{(n+1)!}{n!} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{ (n+1)! }{ k!} \\ 
> &= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{ (n+1)! }{ k!} \\ 
> &= \sum_{k=1}^{ (n+1) -1 } \frac{ (n+1)! }{ k!}, 
> \end{align}
> $$
> as required.

Is this proof correct and clear enough?

Method 2.

> For each $n = 2, 3, 4, \ldots$, if $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then we have
> $$
> \det (A) = \sum_{j = 1}^n a_{ij} A_{ij}.
> $$
> Thus we have the recursive relations
> $$
> s_n = (n-1) + n s_{n-1} \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad m_n = n + n m_{n-1}. 
> $$
> Moreover, we also have $s_1 = 0$ and $m_1 = 0$. [Refer to (1) and (2) above.]

> Backtracking, we obtain
> $$
> \begin{align}
> s_n &= (n-1) + n s_{n-1} \\
> &= (n-1) + n \left( (n-1-1) + (n-1) s_{n-2} \right) \\
> &= (n-1) + n(n-2) + n(n-1) s_{n-2} \\
> &= (n-1) + n(n-2) + n(n-1) \left( (n -2-1) + (n-2) s_{n-3} \right) \\
> &= (n-1) + n(n-2) + n(n-1)(n-3) + n(n-1)(n-2) s_{n-3} \\
> &= \ldots. 
> \end{align}
> $$

Is this calculation correct and accurate? If so, then how to proceed from here?

> We also have
> $$
> \begin{align}
> m_n &= n + n m_{n-1} \\
> &= n + n \left( (n-1) + (n-1) m_{n-2} \right) \\
> &= n + n(n-1) + n(n-1) m_{n-2} \\
> &= n + n(n-1) + n(n-1) \left( (n-2) + (n-2) m_{n-3} \right) \\
> &= n + n(n-1) + n(n-1)(n-2) + n(n-1)(n-2) m_{n-3} \\
> &= n + n(n-1) + n(n-1)(n-2) + n(n-1)(n-2) \left( (n-3) + (n-3) m_{n-4} \right) \\
> &= n + n(n-1) + n(n-1)(n-2) + n(n-1)(n-2) (n-3) + n(n-1)(n-2) (n-3) m_{n-4} \\
> &= \ldots \\
> &= n + n(n-1) + n(n-1)(n-2) + n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) + \cdots + n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\cdots \big(n - (n-1) \big) + n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\cdots \big(n - (n-1) \big) m_{n - (n-1)} \\
> &= n + n(n-1) + n(n-1)(n-2) + n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) + \cdots + n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\cdots \big(n - (n-1) \big) + n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\cdots \big(n - (n-1) \big) m_{1} \\
> &= n + n(n-1) + n(n-1)(n-2) + n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) + \cdots + n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\cdots \big(n - (n-1) \big) \\ 
> &= \frac{n!}{(n-1)!} + \frac{n!}{(n-2)!} + \frac{n!}{(n-3)!} + \cdots + \frac{n!}{1!} \\
> &= \frac{n!}{1!} + \cdots + \frac{n!}{(n-1)!} \\
> &= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{n!}{k!},
> \end{align}
> $$
> as required.

Is this proof correct and clear enough? Or, are there any issues?